# When can the Cauchy principal value be expressed as an improper integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

Consider a Cauchy principal value integral over the real line
$$
I = \operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx f(x)
\tag{1}
$$
where $f(x)$ is a function which is continuous but for finitely many poles $x_n$, all of which are simple, and $f(x)$ decays sufficiently fast as $x \to \pm \infty$ for integrals $\int_{- \infty}^a dx f(x)$, $\int_{b}^\infty dx f(x)$ to converge for $a < \min_n x_n$, $\max_n x_n < b$.

Consider the proposition that the principal value $I$ is equal to the convergent integral
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d x g(x)
\tag2
$$
where $g(x)$ is a function with no poles given by
$$
g(x) = f(x) - \sum_n\frac{\lim_{y\to x_n} f(y)(y-x_n)}{x-x_n}.
$$
Is this proposition true?

For example, for $f(x) = ( \cosh x - \cosh 2)^{-1}$ we have $g(x) = ( \cosh x - \cosh 2)^{-1} - \operatorname{csch} 2 ((x/2)^2 - 1)^{-1}$ and thus obtain $I = 8 e^2 / (1-e^4)$ by evaluating either (1) or (2).

The argument for the proposition is that I am free to add functions of the form $a(x-b)^{-1}$ to the integrand of (1) without altering the principal value of the integral, and can remove all the poles in this manner.

Follow up: can a similar trick be used for higher order poles?

Comment: A small remark: it's principal (adjective) value, not principle (noun).

Comment: @HansLundmark corrected, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The "principal value" at a pole of order $1$ works like this, since the two sides "cancel" when you approach at the same rate.

$$
\int_{x_n-1}^{x_n-\epsilon} \frac{dx}{x-x_n} + \int_{x_n+\epsilon}^{x_n+1}\frac{dx}{x-x_n} = 0 .
$$

---

Another point.
$$
g(x) = f(x) - \sum_n\frac{\lim_{y\to x_n} f(y)(y-x_n)}{x-x_n}.
$$
has no poles.  But its integral may no longer converge at $\pm \infty$.
Example
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x^3-x}
$$
has simple pole at $x=0$, and behaves like $1/|x|^2$ as $x\to\infty$. But
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{x^3-x} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{-x}{x^2+1}
$$
behaves like $1/|x|$ as $|x| \to \infty$, so the integral diverges.  For a PV you will have to use
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{N} \frac{-x\;dx}{x^2+1} .
$$

---

But an integral with a pole of order $2$ diverges even if you attempt a principle value.  Also (usually) poles of order higher than $2$.

Comment: Ok so my take home answer to the question was "yes, if the resulting integral is convergent". Correct me if I have misunderstood.